# Windbg: add multiple unresolved breakpoints

Tags: windbg, breakpoints

I have an unloaded module for which I'd like to add unresolved breakpoints but I can't get it to work.

I have tried

1. to use a wildcard as in `bm`. That doesn't seem to be supported

`bu "RPS32!*"`

2. to explicitly name the methods but each breakpoint get's assigned id 0.This only sets the breakpoint for the last added.

`bu "RPS32!RpsConvertBuffer"`

`bu "RPS32!RpsConvertFile"`

3. to explicitly name the methods *and* the id's. The id's don't seem to stick. Each breakpoint again just redefines id 0 and only the last added is actually set.

`bu39 "RPS32!RpsConvertBuffer"`

`bu40 "RPS32!RpsConvertFile"`

**So my question is actually twofold:**

- Is it possible to have multiple unresolved breakpoints?
- If it's possible, what is wrong with the syntax I'm using?

Comment: have you tried a space between bu and id?
e.g. 'bu 39 "RPS32!RpsConvertBuffer"'?

You could also do a lookup on those functions with the x command: x /D /f RPS32!RpsConvert*

Comment: @GamerJ5 - the module is unloaded when I'm trying to add the breakpoint so the lookup returns nothing. Adding a space changes the semantics. It adds an unresolved breakpoint at address 39 and will execute the command "RPS32!RpsConvertBuffer" when triggered.

Comment: @GamerJ5 - it appears that the quoting is to blame :S. Adding bu breakpoints without quotes works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>The chance of myself running into this same issue again is quite high so I'm pretty much answering my own question out of self interest.</sub>

**Remove the quoting around the methods**

---

Probably this is WinDbg Breakpoint syntax 101 but adding quotes around the method makes WinDbg

- use the address of the current instruction to add an unresolved breakpoint
- reusing Id 0
- and interpreting what's between quotes as a command.

Looking at the breakpoint list, that penny really should have dropped sooner

```
(1e48.1c10): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=08160000 edx=0012e118 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77220ed4 esp=0025f93c ebp=0025f968 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
77220ed4 cc              int     3
0:000> bu "Unresolved1"
0:000> bu "Unresolved2"
breakpoint 0 redefined
0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  77220ed4     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c "Unresolved2"
```